# BindingSource.Filter doesn't work with '!='

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding

I have a binding source and it has a column called `Description` and I want to exclude all rows that have their description set to 'x'.

I have tried:

```
bindingSource.Filter = "Description != ' + x;
```

That doesn't work. Does anyone know how to do a `is not` comparison for the binding source's filter? I couldn't find any help on MSDN.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `<>` instead of `!=`.

See this for more help:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx

Comment: Reference to docs on this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx

Comment: Filtering for binding sources and selecting on datasets works very much like it does in SQL. One thing to note is that if you are filtering on a datetime value, make sure you surround it with pound signs:

   string sFilter = "UpdateDTS > #" + DateTime.Now + "#";

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bindingSource.Filter = String.Format("Description != '{0}'", x);
```

One other thing to try is using `<>` instead of `!=` if the above does still not work.